# Can only create SSH-1 RSA key pair in PuTTYgen on Windows 10

Tags: rsa, putty

I just downloaded what I believe is the latest version of PuTTYgen (
Release 0.73) and used it to generate a public private RSA key pair but
several sources (such as https://docs.joyent.com/public-cloud/getting-started/ssh-keys/generating-an-ssh-key-manually/manually-generating-your-ssh-key-in-windows) indicate I should choose SSH-2 RSA, while my version of PuTTYgen only provides me the option to use SSH-1 RSA. I'm on Windows 10, and am using the key pair for authentication for an app I'm developing (in a development environment). Is it OK to use SSH-1 RSA in the development environment or will I run into problems?

Comment: Thank you. Question answered!

Comment: Up-voted question and answer in the linked question. Thank you again!